# Foreach is only calling the last item in the list

Tags: php, opencart2.x

I don't really think knowledge of OpenCart would help too much with answering this question, but maybe I am wrong.

I am using OpenCart to make a shop. I am making edits to my categories.tpl page, and everything was looking good. I only had one product when I was doing the edits so it was normal that it was only showing one product. Before I did the edits, I did check the same page with many of the products you start with and it was working fine.

Here is my code right now, which is only calling the last product (I'm guessing item in an array or in a SQL sheet)

```
<?php echo $header; ?>
<div class="container">
<?php foreach ($breadcrumbs as $breadcrumb) { ?>
        <?php } ?>
 <div class="row"><?php echo $column_left; ?>
    <?php if ($column_left && $column_right) { ?>
    <?php $class = 'col-sm-6'; ?>
    <?php } elseif ($column_left || $column_right) { ?>
    <?php $class = 'col-sm-9'; ?>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <?php $class = 'col-sm-12'; ?>
    <?php } ?>
    <div id="content" class="<?php echo $class; ?>"><?php echo $content_top; ?>
           <?php if ($thumb || $description) { ?>
      <div class="row">
        <?php if ($thumb) { ?>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if ($description) { ?><?php } ?>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <?php } ?>

<?php if ($categories) { ?>
      <h3><?php echo $text_refine; ?></h3>
      <?php if (count($categories) <= 5) { ?>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          </div>
      <?php }
?>
      <?php } ?>
       <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
      </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 text-right">
          </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 text-right">
     <button type="button" id="grid-view"  style="display: none;"></button>
               </div>
        </div><br />
      <div class="row">
        <?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
        <div class="product-layout product-list col-xs-12">
          <div class="product-thumb">
            <div class="image"><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $product['thumb']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" title="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
            <div>
              <div class="caption">
                <h4><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></a></h4>
                <p><?php echo $product['description']; ?></p>
                <?php if ($product['rating']) { ?>
                <div class="rating">
                  <?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) { ?>
                  <?php if ($product['rating'] < $i) { ?>
                  <span class="fa fa-stack"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-stack-2x"></i></span>
                  <?php } else { ?>
                  <span class="fa fa-stack"><i class="fa fa-star fa-stack-2x"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-stack-2x"></i></span>
                  <?php } ?>
                  <?php } ?>
                </div>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php if ($product['price']) { ?>
                <p class="price">
                  <?php if (!$product['special']) { ?>
                  <?php echo $product['price']; ?>
                  <?php } else { ?>
                  <span class="price-new"><?php echo $product['special']; ?></span> <span class="price-old"><?php echo $product['price']; ?></span>
                  <?php } ?>
                  </p>
                <?php } ?>
              </div>
              <div class="button-group">
                <button style="width:100%;" type="button" onclick="cart.add('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>', '<?php echo $product['minimum']; ?>');"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md"><?php echo $button_cart; ?></span></button>
</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 text-left"><?php echo $pagination; ?></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 text-right"><?php echo $results; ?></div>
      </div>
      <?php } ?>
      <?php if (!$categories && !$products) { ?>
      <p><?php echo $text_empty; ?></p>
      <div class="buttons">
        <div class="pull-right"><a href="<?php echo $continue; ?>" class="btn btn-primary"><?php echo $button_continue; ?></a></div>
      </div>
      <?php } ?>
      <?php echo $content_bottom; ?></div>
    <?php echo $column_right; ?></div>
</div>
<?php echo $footer; ?>
```

And here is the code I started with, which worked correctly.

```
<?php echo $header; ?>
<div class="container">
  <ul class="breadcrumb">
    <?php foreach ($breadcrumbs as $breadcrumb) { ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $breadcrumb['href']; ?>"><?php echo $breadcrumb['text']; ?></a></li>
    <?php } ?>
  </ul>
  <div class="row"><?php echo $column_left; ?>
    <?php if ($column_left && $column_right) { ?>
    <?php $class = 'col-sm-6'; ?>
    <?php } elseif ($column_left || $column_right) { ?>
    <?php $class = 'col-sm-9'; ?>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <?php $class = 'col-sm-12'; ?>
    <?php } ?>
    <div id="content" class="<?php echo $class; ?>"><?php echo $content_top; ?>
      <h2><?php echo $heading_title; ?></h2>
      <?php if ($thumb || $description) { ?>
      <div class="row">
        <?php if ($thumb) { ?>
        <div class="col-sm-2"><img src="<?php echo $thumb; ?>" alt="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" class="img-thumbnail" /></div>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if ($description) { ?>
        <div class="col-sm-10"><?php echo $description; ?></div>
        <?php } ?>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <?php } ?>
      <?php if ($categories) { ?>
      <h3><?php echo $text_refine; ?></h3>
      <?php if (count($categories) <= 5) { ?>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <ul>
            <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a></li>
            <?php } ?>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <?php } else { ?>
      <div class="row">
        <?php foreach (array_chunk($categories, ceil(count($categories) / 4)) as $categories) { ?>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <ul>
            <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a></li>
            <?php } ?>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
      </div>
      <?php } ?>
      <?php } ?>
      <?php if ($products) { ?>
      <p><a href="<?php echo $compare; ?>" id="compare-total"><?php echo $text_compare; ?></a></p>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="btn-group hidden-xs">
            <button type="button" id="list-view" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_list; ?>"><i class="fa fa-th-list"></i></button>
            <button type="button" id="grid-view" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_grid; ?>"><i class="fa fa-th"></i></button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 text-right">
          <label class="control-label" for="input-sort"><?php echo $text_sort; ?></label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 text-right">
          <select id="input-sort" class="form-control" onchange="location = this.value;">
            <?php foreach ($sorts as $sorts) { ?>
            <?php if ($sorts['value'] == $sort . '-' . $order) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $sorts['href']; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $sorts['text']; ?></option>
            <?php } else { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $sorts['href']; ?>"><?php echo $sorts['text']; ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php } ?>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1 text-right">
          <label class="control-label" for="input-limit"><?php echo $text_limit; ?></label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 text-right">
          <select id="input-limit" class="form-control" onchange="location = this.value;">
            <?php foreach ($limits as $limits) { ?>
            <?php if ($limits['value'] == $limit) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $limits['href']; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $limits['text']; ?></option>
            <?php } else { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $limits['href']; ?>"><?php echo $limits['text']; ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php } ?>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br />
      <div class="row">
        <?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
        <div class="product-layout product-list col-xs-12">
          <div class="product-thumb">
            <div class="image"><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $product['thumb']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" title="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
            <div>
              <div class="caption">
                <h4><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></a></h4>
                <p><?php echo $product['description']; ?></p>
                <?php if ($product['rating']) { ?>
                <div class="rating">
                  <?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) { ?>
                  <?php if ($product['rating'] < $i) { ?>
                  <span class="fa fa-stack"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-stack-2x"></i></span>
                  <?php } else { ?>
                  <span class="fa fa-stack"><i class="fa fa-star fa-stack-2x"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-stack-2x"></i></span>
                  <?php } ?>
                  <?php } ?>
                </div>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php if ($product['price']) { ?>
                <p class="price">
                  <?php if (!$product['special']) { ?>
                  <?php echo $product['price']; ?>
                  <?php } else { ?>
                  <span class="price-new"><?php echo $product['special']; ?></span> <span class="price-old"><?php echo $product['price']; ?></span>
                  <?php } ?>
                  <?php if ($product['tax']) { ?>
                  <span class="price-tax"><?php echo $text_tax; ?> <?php echo $product['tax']; ?></span>
                  <?php } ?>
                </p>
                <?php } ?>
              </div>
              <div class="button-group">
                <button type="button" onclick="cart.add('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>', '<?php echo $product['minimum']; ?>');"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md"><?php echo $button_cart; ?></span></button>
                <button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_wishlist; ?>" onclick="wishlist.add('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></button>
                <button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_compare; ?>" onclick="compare.add('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');"><i class="fa fa-exchange"></i></button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 text-left"><?php echo $pagination; ?></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 text-right"><?php echo $results; ?></div>
      </div>
      <?php } ?>
      <?php if (!$categories && !$products) { ?>
      <p><?php echo $text_empty; ?></p>
      <div class="buttons">
        <div class="pull-right"><a href="<?php echo $continue; ?>" class="btn btn-primary"><?php echo $button_continue; ?></a></div>
      </div>
      <?php } ?>
      <?php echo $content_bottom; ?></div>
    <?php echo $column_right; ?></div>
</div>
<?php echo $footer; ?>
```

Thanks in advance for anyone who could try and figure out why it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Here, have not add properly close tag for foreach php loop.

Try following code in your editing file.

```
<?php echo $header; ?>
<div class="container">
<?php foreach ($breadcrumbs as $breadcrumb) { ?>
        <?php } ?>
 <div class="row"><?php echo $column_left; ?>
    <?php if ($column_left && $column_right) { ?>
    <?php $class = 'col-sm-6'; ?>
    <?php } elseif ($column_left || $column_right) { ?>
    <?php $class = 'col-sm-9'; ?>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <?php $class = 'col-sm-12'; ?>
    <?php } ?>
    <div id="content" class="<?php echo $class; ?>"><?php echo $content_top; ?>
<?php if ($categories) { ?>
      <h3><?php echo $text_refine; ?></h3>

      <?php } ?>
       <br />
      <div>
        <?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
        <div class="product-layout product-list col-xs-12">
          <div class="product-thumb">
            <div class="image"><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $product['thumb']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" title="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
            <div>
              <div class="caption">
                <h4><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></a></h4>
                <p><?php echo $product['description']; ?></p>
                <?php if ($product['rating']) { ?>
                <div class="rating">
                  <?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) { ?>
                  <?php if ($product['rating'] < $i) { ?>
                  <span class="fa fa-stack"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-stack-2x"></i></span>
                  <?php } else { ?>
                  <span class="fa fa-stack"><i class="fa fa-star fa-stack-2x"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-stack-2x"></i></span>
                  <?php } ?>
                  <?php } ?>
                </div>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php if ($product['price']) { ?>
                <p class="price">
                  <?php if (!$product['special']) { ?>
                  <?php echo $product['price']; ?>
                  <?php } else { ?>
                  <span class="price-new"><?php echo $product['special']; ?></span> <span class="price-old"><?php echo $product['price']; ?></span>
                  <?php } ?>
                  </p>
                <?php } ?>
              </div>
              <div class="button-group">
                <button style="width:100%;" type="button" onclick="cart.add('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>', '<?php echo $product['minimum']; ?>');"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md"><?php echo $button_cart; ?></span></button>
</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div><?php } ?>
        </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 text-left"><?php echo $pagination; ?></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 text-right"><?php echo $results; ?></div>
      </div>

      <?php if (!$categories && !$products) { ?>
      <p><?php echo $text_empty; ?></p>
      <div class="buttons">
        <div class="pull-right"><a href="<?php echo $continue; ?>" class="btn btn-primary"><?php echo $button_continue; ?></a></div>
      </div>
      <?php } ?>
      <?php echo $content_bottom; ?></div>
    <?php echo $column_right; ?></div>
</div>
<?php echo $footer; ?>
```